# Calculating difference between row vector and average row vector?

Tags: python

Suppose the matrix is M=

```
[[.10, .32, .20, .40, .80], 
 [.23, .18, .56, .61, .12], 
 [.90, .30, .60, .50, .30], 
 [.34, .75, .91, .19, .21]]
```

The average row vector is rav=

```
[ 0.3925  0.3875  0.5675  0.425   0.3575]
```

I want to subtract average row vector (rav) from each row vector in the above matrix (M) 
i.e M(i)-rav.
How can I do that in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure Python

```
>>> [[i-j for i,j in zip(m, rav)] for m in M]
[[-0.2925, -0.0675, -0.3675, -0.024999999999999967, 0.44250000000000006], [-0.1625, -0.20750000000000002, -0.007499999999999951, 0.185, -0.2375], [0.5075000000000001, -0.08750000000000002, 0.03249999999999997, 0.07500000000000001, -0.057499999999999996], [-0.05249999999999999, 0.3625, 0.3425, -0.235, -0.1475]]
```

It will be faster to use numpy if you are doing a bunch of matrix operations. Converting to and from numpy matrices is fairly expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using numpy, this is as simple as:

```
M = np.asarray(M) # make sure M is an array...it presumably would be
rav = np.mean(M, axis=0)
diffs = M - rav
```

which works due to [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

If you're using plain lists, it's a little more complicated and the code will be much slower, but something like this should do it:

```
# M is a list of num_rows lists of num_cols floats
rav = [sum(row[j] for row in M) / num_rows for j in range(num_cols)]
diffs = [[x - mean_x for x, mean_x in zip(row, rav)] for row in M]
```

Comment: thank yoy very much. it works. another thing, how do I normalize each row vecor efficiently. i,e each row vector is divided by the length of each vector.